# Find a specific file in a directory and delete directory

Tags: directory

Im new to python and trying things . Is it possible to walk true a tree searching for specific file name , after finding that file delete the whole folder were that file is found?

The following works , but only deletes the file , i want to delete the whole folder when addon.sxm is found

```
    if os.path.exists(Addons):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(Addons):
            package_count = 0
            package_count += len(files)
                if package_count > 0:
                    for f in files:
                        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, 'addon.sxm'):
                            try:
                                os.remove(os.path.join(root, f)) 
                            except:
                                pass
            else:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))** use **shutil.rmtree(root);** it will remove directory where file is located.

```
import os
import fnmatch
import shutil
Addons="/path/to/my/folder/"
if os.path.exists(Addons):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(Addons):
        package_count = 0
        package_count += len(files)
        if package_count > 0:
            for f in files:
                print(f)
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, 'addon.sxm'):
                    try:
                        shutil.rmtree(root);
                    except:
                        pass
        else:
            pass
```